# Speeding up a simple for loop with vectorization in R

Tags: r, vectorization

In R, I have a simple for loop with a function inside. It takes a data frame and looks at the row directly before to find the distance and then populates the dist column. Everything works perfectly but it takes a long time to run on over 120,000 rows (over 5 minutes). Finding a (likely vectorized) way to speed up this function would be greatly appreciated. Just for full disclosure, I have asked a similar question before, but the parameters I needed ended up changing and I was unable to adapt that answer to the new changes.

Sample Data:

```
lat <- c(32.88084254, 32.88058801, 32.88034199, 32.88027623, 32.88022759)
lon <- c(-117.23543042, -117.23606292, -117.23654377, -117.23723468, -117.23788206)
tripData <- data.frame(cbind(lat, lon))
tripData["dists"] <- NA


for (i in 2:nrow(tripData)) {
tripData$dists[i] <- geodist(tripData[i, c("lat")], 
                                tripData[i, c("lon")],
                                tripData[i-1, c("lat")], 
                                tripData[i-1, c("lon")],
                                units="km")*1000
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the function `geodist` from the package **gmt**, it's documentation states that it already is vectorized:

```
gmt::geodist(tripData[2:5, "lat"], 
        tripData[2:5, "lon"],
        tripData[1:4, "lat"], 
        tripData[1:4, "lon"],
        units="km")*1000
```

A small side note: stop doing `data.frame(cbind(lat, lon))`. You gain nothing compared to `data.frame(lat,lon)` and you risk much.

Comment: +1 Or more generally `tripData$lat[-1]` and `tripData$lat[ - nrow( tripData ) ]`, but it is a bit more of a mouthful.

Comment: This is perfect, SO much faster. I need to make sure to read documentation more closely. Also, thanks for the tip. All of my R is self-taught, so I end up missing out on learning a lot of the idiosyncrasies.

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize function calls with multiple arguments using `mapply` (multivariate sapply).

```
n <- nrow(tripdata)
mapply(geodist,
       tripdata$lat[-1], tripdata$lon[-1],
       tripdata$lat[-n], tripdata$lon[-n],
       moreArgs=list(units="km"))*1000
```